# Retrieve results from database with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join

I tried to reduce the number of operations of a function to only one query, but now I can't retrieve any result:

```
function retrive_avaible_operator($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName, $SupportUserPerDepaTable, $SupportUserTable,$dep){
    $query = "SELECT b.id  
              FROM ".$SupportUserTable." b
              INNER JOIN ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." a
                  ON b.id=a.user_id
              WHERE a.department_id=? AND b.holiday='0' AND a.user_id!=".$_SESSION['id']." 
              ORDER BY b.assigned_tickets ASC LIMIT 1";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
    $stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
    $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);

    if($prepared){
        if($stmt->bind_param('i', $dep)){
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $stmt->store_result();
                $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
                if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                        $selopid=$camaro;
                    return $selopid;
                }
                else
                    return 'No Operator Available';
            }
            else
                return mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        }
        else
            return mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
    }
    else
        return mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
}
```

Before this try the operations were (these are 2 different queries):

1. select all the id from `$SupportUserPerDepaTable` where `a.department_id=?`
2. select all the id from `$SupportUserTable` where id is inside the previous results and `holiday='0'`

It worked, but now it returns only `No Operator Available`

Also these are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_user_departments` (
`id`                BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT,
`department_id`     BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
`department_name`   VARCHAR(70)             NOT NULL,
`user_id`           BIGINT(11)  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL,
`holiday`           ENUM('0','1')           NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`department_name`,`user_id`),
INDEX(`department_id`,`department_name`,`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `razorphyn_support_users` (
`id`                BIGINT(15)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name`              VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`mail`              VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`password`          VARCHAR(200)                    NOT NULL,
`reg_key`           VARCHAR(260)                    ,
`tmp_password`      VARCHAR(87)                     ,
`ip_address`        VARCHAR(50)                     NOT NULL,
`status`            ENUM('0','1','2','3','4')       NOT NULL    DEFAULT '3',
`holiday`           ENUM('0','1')                   NOT NULL    DEFAULT '0',
`mail_alert`        ENUM('no','yes')                NOT NULL    DEFAULT 'yes',
`assigned_tickets`  INT(5)          UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`solved_tickets`    BIGINT(11)      UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`number_rating`     BIGINT(6)       UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
`rating`            DECIMAL(4,2)    UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY(`mail`),
INDEX (`name`,`mail`,`status`,`holiday`,`assigned_tickets`,`solved_tickets`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=55;
```

**EDIT**
I have found(unfortunately, beacuse is very ugly and messy) the previous code( I have removed all the control if, but it works):

```
function retrive_avaible_operator($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName, $SupportUserPerDepaTable, $SupportUserTable,$dep){

$query = "SELECT `user_id`  FROM ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." WHERE `department_id`=? AND `user_id`!=".$_SESSION['id'] ;
$mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $dep)
        $stmt->execute()
            $stmt->store_result();
            $operator=array();
            $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
            if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                    $operator[]=$camaro;
                $operator=join(',',$operator);
                $query = "SELECT `id`  FROM ".$SupportUserTable." WHERE `id` IN (".$operator.") AND `holiday`='0' ORDER BY `assigned_tickets` ASC LIMIT 1" ;
                $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
                $prepared)
                    $stmt->execute()
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
                        if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                                $selopid=$camaro;
                            return $selopid;
                        }
                        else{
                            $query = "SELECT `id` FROM ".$SupportUserTable." WHERE `status`=2 AND `holiday`=0 AND `id`!=".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY `assigned_tickets` ASC, `solved_tickets` ASC LIMIT 1" ;
                            $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
                            $prepared
                                $stmt->execute()
                                    $stmt->store_result();
                                    $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
                                    if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                                        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                                            $selopid=$camaro;
                                        return $selopid;
                                    }
                                    else
                                        return 'No Operator Available';
                        }
            }
            else{
                $query = "SELECT `id` FROM ".$SupportUserTable." WHERE `status`='2' AND `holiday`='0' AND `id`!=".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY `assigned_tickets` ASC, `solved_tickets` ASC LIMIT 1" ;
                $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
                    $stmt->execute()
                        $stmt->store_result();
                        $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
                        if($stmt->num_rows>0){
                            while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
                                $selopid=$camaro;
                            return $selopid;
                        }
                        else
                            return 'No Operator Available';
            }
$mysqli->close();
}
```

Comment: That is one gnarly set of nested `if` statements. Consider using [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: This is not the first time that someone says that, but I don't understantd how, mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) is an execption or an error?

Comment: Hmm. After some further reading, apparently mySQLi doesn't work so well with exceptions. I guess that's all the more reason [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). That's just my opinion of course. try/catch is a lot easier than trying to check every possible error condition. It also keeps the error handling out of the logical flow of the program.

Comment: Have you checked the query produced and tested it?  May be the problem is there??

Comment: The query doesn't return any error

Comment: @Herbert I have tried one time, but the function goes on until the end, it doesn't return any error and so the calling function receive a wrong output, maybe a `exit()` could solve the problem, but for now this is not my priority

Comment: @Dheed hi, is there any update related to the problem? I am going to help, but need any further update if you made any beside the latest one showing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to condense this considerably. In the beginning, you query your `$SupportUserPerDepaTable` just to get the user_id, only to join them into a comma seperated string for your 2nd query. You should be able to eliminate this by turning it into a subquery. The 3rd and 4th queries are redundant, a product of the previous if/else case, so you can combine those now that we have eliminated the top if condition. Using the bottom "ugly" code, I condensed it to this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $DatabaseName);
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$query = "
SELECT      `id`  
FROM        ".$SupportUserTable." 
WHERE       `id` IN (
    SELECT      `user_id`  
    FROM        ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." 
    WHERE       `department_id`= ? 
    AND         `user_id`!=".$_SESSION['id']."
)
AND         `holiday`='0'
ORDER BY    `assigned_tickets` ASC 
LIMIT       1" ;

$prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $dep);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$operator=array();
$result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
if($stmt->num_rows>0){
    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
        $selopid=$camaro;
    return $selopid;
}
else{
    $query = "
    SELECT      `id` 
    FROM        ".$SupportUserTable." 
    WHERE       `status`= 2 
    AND         `holiday`=0 
    AND         `id`!=".$_SESSION['id']." 
    ORDER BY    `assigned_tickets` ASC
                ,`solved_tickets`  ASC 
    LIMIT       1" ;
    $prepared = $stmt->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $result = $stmt->bind_result($camaro);
    if($stmt->num_rows>0){
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))
            $selopid=$camaro;
        return $selopid;
    }
    else{
        return 'No Operator Available';
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

You may be able to further condense the 2 queries into 1 by using a UNION with a combined limit of 1 like:

```
(
    SELECT      `id`  
    FROM        ".$SupportUserTable." 
    WHERE       `id` IN (
        SELECT      `user_id`  
        FROM        ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." 
        WHERE       `department_id`= ? 
        AND         `user_id`!=".$_SESSION['id']."
    )
    AND         `holiday`='0'
    ORDER BY    `assigned_tickets` ASC 
    UNION
    SELECT      `id` 
        FROM        ".$SupportUserTable." 
        WHERE       `status`= 2 
        AND         `holiday`=0 
        AND         `id`!=".$_SESSION['id']." 
        ORDER BY    `assigned_tickets` ASC
                    ,`solved_tickets`  ASC 
)
LIMIT       1;
```

or possibly using an `OR` condition depending on the status code of an employee in the dept table like:

```
SELECT      `id`  
FROM        ".$SupportUserTable." 
WHERE       `holiday`='0'
AND (       
        `id`    IN (
            SELECT      `user_id`  
            FROM        ".$SupportUserPerDepaTable." 
            WHERE       `department_id`= ? 
            AND         `user_id`!=".$_SESSION['id']."
        )
        AND     `status`= ('some code other than 2?') 
    )
    OR  (
                `status`= 2 
        AND     `id`! = ".$_SESSION['id']."
)
ORDER BY    status (asc or desc?)
            ,`assigned_tickets` ASC
            ,`solved_tickets`  ASC 
LIMIT       1;
```

I havent tested this as that would take too much time to setup database tables, input sample data and test it all out, so forgive me if there are any small errors, but this should point you in the right direction. If this doesnt work and you want to post some sample data to http://sqlfiddle.com/ and give a couple examples of expected output I'll retry some queries to see what I can do.

Comment: I don't know why, but it started working the query of the question, however isn't a bad practise to use SELECT inside a SELECT query?

Comment: Be wary of queries that "suddenly work" when they hadn't before, as they may only work under certain conditions when you accidentally select what you want... If your subselect table had millions of rows, it would certainly slow down the query, but if its a reasonable size (dozens, hundreds), and especially if your tables are properly indexed it should still be pretty quick. Either way its going to be more efficient than doing a query to loop through values appending to a text string only to use that text string in a 2nd query.